# Get social user info in view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, social-media

I am using laravel social auth guide and I dont know how can I get users info from database. 
To get info by auth user I can use
    Auth::user()->id; to get info by users created by normal register. How get id of user logged by socialmedia?

Comment: There is a part about [social authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication) in the docs.

Comment: For Facebook, I keep the user's ID in the database and I keep their authentication token in there with it for the duration of their login. Then use the two to make API calls. I'm sure there's a better way to do that, but it's how I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Socialite` class and  `facebook` service provider:

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```

Once, you get the user instance, you can get few more details with:

```
$user->name;
$user->email;
```

See [Social authentication](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) using Socialite for more.